# 2D animated show/movie with a group of people travelling back in time, held captive by a tribe; one of them is a redhead girl

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon, animation

I watched this animated show/movie back when I was kid, it was a 2D animated movie that had a group of people who somehow time traveled back in time (accidentally, I think) and the characters were in some sort of show(?) it’s really hazy to me now

I think at one point they were held captive by a tribe.

I also remembered one of the characters being a redhead girl with freckles who snorts when she laughs and she’s really insecure about her laugh at first, but then this dude is all like “cute”.

Comment: Hi there! Could you maybe [edit] in some more info about that, like (roughly) when you watched that? Was it in English, was it a translation? If you saw that on TV, any idea which channel it could have aired on?

Comment: Could you provide an approximate date when you saw this show? Basically: when were you a kid? ;)

Comment: Hi! I’m almost 100% sure it’s in english and i think it came out roughly around the late 90’s to early 2000’s